# Bootstrap yielding counterintuitive results (Update: but not anymore)

Tags: r, regression, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, bootstrap

I have some experience in using bootstrap methods and I'm back to them after a really long hiatus. However, I'm almost certain I'm doing something wrong and, after a lot of time trying to figure out what it is, I'm sure I won't find out by myself.

---

I'm going to provide a MWE to see if anyone can help me. My simplest attempt is trying to test:

$\begin{cases}
H_0:NOx=\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^5a_iE^i+\varepsilon \text{ for some }a\in\mathbb R^6\\
H_1:NOx=s(E)+\varepsilon \text{ for some smooth }s\text{ (that's not a polynomial of degree $\leq5$) }
\end{cases}$

for continuous RVs $NOx$ and $E$ from the *ethanol* data at the R package *lattice*. So the models would be:

```
require(lattice);data(ethanol)
M0<-lm(NOx~E+I(E^2)+I(E^3)+I(E^4)+I(E^5),data=ethanol)
M1<-mgcv::gam(NOx~s(E),data=ethanol)
```

---

My test statistic is the relative difference of RSS:

```
RSS0<-sum(residuals(M0)^2)
RSS1<-sum(residuals(M1)^2)
R<-(RSS0-RSS1)/RSS1
```

and I approximate its null distribution via [*wild bootstrap* (the gold ratio one, Mammen [1993])](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)#Wild_bootstrap) the following way:

```
adj0<-predict(M0)
res0<-residuals(M0)
sigma0<-sd(res0)
n<-nrow(ethanol)

set.seed(1)
B<-1000;Rstar<-rep(NA,B);ethanolstar<-ethanol
veplus<-res0*(1+sqrt(5))/2
veminus<-res0*(1-sqrt(5))/2
for (b in 1:B){
  ii<-rbinom(n,1,(5+sqrt(5))/10)
  ethanolstar$NOx<-adj0+veminus*ii+veplus*(1-ii)
  M0star<-lm(NOx~E+I(E^2)+I(E^3)+I(E^4)+I(E^5),data=ethanolstar)
  M1star<-mgcv::gam(NOx~s(E),data=ethanolstar)
  RSS1star<-sum(residuals(M1star)^2)
  RSS0star<-sum(residuals(M0star)^2)
  Rstar[b]<-(RSS0star-RSS1star)/RSS1star
}
cat("p-value:",mean(Rstar>R),"\n")
```

---

Finally, I get a *p*-value of 0.01.

Similarly, when I use the **simple Gaussian bootstrap**, that is, defining:

```
ethanolstar$NOx<-rnorm(n,adj0,sigma0)
```

at each iteration, I get a *p*-value of 0.001.

---

**Why I suspect these results to be wrong.**

A simple plot suggests that a low *p*-value shouldn't be expected:
[image]
And, on top of that, I get really low *p*-values for a variety of examples in which the null model is correct.

---

So, **(why) is my R code wrong?**

Comment: I don't know very much about bootstrap methods, but are there problems caused by mgcv doing model selection inside the simulation?  Of your 1000 M1Star models, 750 report a lower "effective degrees of freedom" than M1. The 10 simulated Rstar values bigger than R all occur when M1Star edf is bigger than M1's edf.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the feedback! I'm not using mgcv::gam to do model selection—I just use it to obtain the corresponding residuals. Anyway, I don't think I'm understanding your comment very well... How are those "lower effective degrees of freedom" making the results go wrong? What do EDF have to do with the problem?

Comment: Why do you believe that the test should not reject based on the plot? It looks to me like the polynomial fit is horrible in the right part of the plot; that could easily lead to rejection.

Comment: @guy exactly, there *is* a 20% reduction in residual sum of squares using the GAM model.

Comment: Thanks for your help, guy and @AdamO. I had already thought about that (yet, I've edited the question to be less assertive). But I'm still worried about the fact that with **several** examples the same thing's going on... I'll check the simulated models once more, just in case. In hindsight, I should have used one of those for my OP, as they are less simple but clearer.

Comment: By the way, has any of you taken a glance to the R code itself? Does it seem to contain any serious misunderstanding of the bootstrap?

Comment: (+1) @jpz, I ran your code and as far as I can tell, it seems okay. I tried re-running the Gaussian bootstrap on a single dataset generated under $H_0$ (itself from a Gaussian bootstrap) and got a nominal rejection rate as expected.

Comment: Thanks, @half-pass. That's helpful! However, not all my simulations seem to go right. I'll keep checking.

Comment: In the meantime, any further thoughts are welcome!

Comment: @jpz Model selection was probably the wrong term in this case, but I mean that the s() term in your gam has a smoothing parameter which is being selected by mgcv "under the hood", and that your simulated models are being smoothed more than your original. Anyway it might not be a problem at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the bootstrap is not wrong. What's wrong is the test statistic you're using. The residual sum of squares is calculated using internal validation. The GAM is overfitting the curve. Polynomials approximations obtained from least squares are known to fit relatively badly in the tails, which is actually where a reasonable amount of the ethanol exposure measures are concentrated. Try modifying your approach to use split-sample validation.

I get a much more conservative estimate of the incremental predictive accuracy of the GAM using this suggested modification of your program:

```
require(lattice)
library(mgcv)

data(ethanol)
set.seed(123)
## 80/20 test/valid
nr <- nrow(ethanol)
split0 <- sample(1:nr, floor(0.8*nr))
split1 <- setdiff(1:nr, split0)

## to generate data under the null
M0 <- lm(NOx~E+I(E^2)+I(E^3)+I(E^4)+I(E^5),data=ethanol[split0,])
res0 <- residuals(M0)

fitntest <- function(ethanol, split0, split1) {
  M0 <- lm(NOx~E+I(E^2)+I(E^3)+I(E^4)+I(E^5),data=ethanol[split0,])
  M1 <- gam(NOx~s(E),data=ethanol[split0,])
  RSS0 <- sum({ethanol[split1, 'NOx']-predict(M0, newdata=ethanol[split1, ])}^2)
  RSS1 <- sum({ethanol[split1, 'NOx']-predict(M1, newdata=ethanol[split1, ])}^2)
  (RSS0-RSS1)/RSS1
}

R <- fitntest(ethanol, split0, split1)
Rstar <- replicate(1000, {
  ethanol$NOx <- predict(M0, newdata=ethanol) + rnorm(nr, 0, sd(res0))
  fitntest(ethanol, split0, split1)
})
cat("p-value:",mean(Rstar>R),"\n")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, @AdamO! I've used your approach with a few examples and it seems to work fine! But I don't know if I'm understanding the formal justification of the need for split-sample validation. Can anybody tell me if what I say below is right?

Comment: In my OP I use the whole sample to find the best $\hat a\in\mathbb R^6$ by looking at the residuals of M0, and the same for $\hat s$ in M1. Then I compute the RSS's with the same data, which means that these RSS's will be as low as possible (overfitting).

So in the end it's the same as fitting a model with some data and affirming that the model's great because it fits the data very well, which is the typical circular argument that motivates cross-validation.

Comment: Finally, wouldn't it be necessary to use K-fold cross-validation for $K>1$ rather than $K=1$? Why (not)?

Comment: @jpz the reason is that internal validation is too optimistic and so favors the GAM which has a tendency to overfit relative to a 5 degree polynomial. Using $k$-fold cross validation is yet another way to demote the "optimistm" of the GAM. By all means consider it!

Comment: OK. I understand that the GAM overfits more than the polynomial model due to its greater number of parameters. But the crucial point here is that both are overfitting, since at the end of the day you're using split-sample validation on both models. Right?

Comment: @jpz Whether they both overfit, I dunno. A 6 parameter model doesn't seem crazy for the sample size and number of points. The point is this: what's going to fit a model better on the basis of RSS alone? A 5 degree polynomial or a 6 degree polynomial? The latter, right? Then remember that the GAM is intended to fit a function of nearly any form. It's more intuition than an appellation to "overfitting"

Comment: Oh, I see. So the point you're trying to make is that the RSS's from the GAM are deflated and, as a result, my original statistic was too large and that's why the corresponding test was too "liberal"/"anti-conservative"/"optimistic"? Anyway, cross-validation won't harm in any context and it doesn't require a solid justification, does it?

Comment: One last question before I accept the answer... How would it be adapted to the wild bootstrap? If I do the following:

Comment: veplus<-res0*(1+sqrt(5))/2;veminus<-res0*(1-sqrt(5))/2;ii<-rbinom(nr,1,(5+sqrt(5))/10);ethanolstar$NOx<-predict(M0,ethanol)+veminus*ii+veplus*(1-ii)

Comment: Then I'm filling the positions corresponding to split1 using the residuals from M0, that came from split0. Ins't that what I was trying to avoid? (Not to mention the warnings due to the different lengths)

Comment: @jpz (Use backticks \` to `monospace` code in `comments`). I think that's right. Use the `split0` and `split1` vector to select residuals from the respective train/valid samples. Try it and report back?

Comment: Oh, thanks heaps for the backticks tip! As for your suggestion on how to choose the residuals, it seems to lead to coherent results, so I think I can move on. I'm most grateful for all your help, Adam.